# Filtering a list using Java 8 lambda expressions

Tags: java, lambda, filter, java-8, java-stream

I have a `Project` class:

```
class Project {
    List<Name> names;
    int year;
    public List<Name> getNames(){
        return names;
    }
}
```

Then I have another main function where I have a `List<Project>` and have to filter that list of projects on the basis of year and get names list as the result.

Can you please tell me how to do it using java 8 lambda expressions?

Thanks

Comment: have you written what you are trying to do already without using java 8 features. We will be happy to help you go from that to using streams and lambda.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, you didn't state the exact filtering condition, but assuming you wish to filter elements by a given year:

```
List<Name> names = projects.stream()
    .filter(p -> p.getYear() == someYear) // keep only projects of a 
                                         // given year
    .flatMap(p -> p.getNames().stream()) // get a Stream of all the
                                        // Names of all Projects
                                        // that passed the filter
    .collect(Collectors.toList());     // collect to a List
```